# Setting up Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a `User` model, `Post` model and `Bookmark` model. How do i need to set up relationship among them so that I can use `current_user.bookmarks.posts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bookmarks
end

class Bookmark < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bookmark
end
```

Comment: If I am trying to use this in console `User.all[0].bookmarks.posts` it is throwing an error  `undefined method `posts' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`
I have used user_id and post_id in bookmark table

Comment: Because you must also access a specific bookmark, as you did with the user.

Comment: Sorry..I don't understand what are you trying to say.
I just want all posts which user add as bookmarks using user_bookmarks_posts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to get all the posts that belong to the user, then you can use the [has_many :through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bookmarks
  has_many :posts, through: :bookmarks
end

class Bookmark < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bookmark
end
```

Then you can just call:

```
user = User.first
all_posts = user.posts
```

It will return an array containing all the posts for each of the bookmarks belonging to the user.